# How to display and hide a div with CSS?

Tags: css, html, hover, siblings

In my script there are three divs. I want to display div with `class="ab"` when I hover on first line and display div with `class="abc"`, when hover on second line. Otherwise I want to display div with `class="a"` by default.

But it never displays the div with `class="a"`.

```css
.abc,.ab {
    display: none;
}
#f:hover ~ .ab {
    display: block;

}
#f:hover ~ .abc,.a {
    display: none;

}
#s:hover ~ .abc {
    display: block;

}
#s:hover ~ .ab,.a {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<a id="f">Show First content!</a>
<br/>
<a id="s">Show Second content!!</a>
<div class="a">Default Content</div>
<div class="ab">First content</div>
<div class="abc">Second content</div>
```

Here is my JSFiddle of my problem: [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/mridulpv/n5fzB/1/)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need

```
.abc,.ab {
    display: none;
}

#f:hover ~ .ab {
    display: block;
}

#s:hover ~ .abc {
    display: block;
}

#s:hover ~ .a,
#f:hover ~ .a{
    display: none;
}
```

**Updated demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/n5fzB/2/

---

The problem in your original CSS was that the `,` in css selectors starts a completely new selector. it is not combined.. so `#f:hover ~ .abc,.a` means `#f:hover ~ .abc` and `.a`. You set that to `display:none` so it was always set to be hidden for all `.a` elements.

Comment: Ahhh that's what he meant. He could have just said "Hide `.a` when one of the others is hovered over".

Comment: Thanks ! It work ! But still I don't understand, why my script never display div with class a. :(

Comment: @mridul, because the `,` in css selectors starts a completely new selector. it is not combined.. so `#f:hover ~ .abc,.a` means `#f:hover ~ .abc` and `.a`. You set that to `display:none` so it was always set to be hidden

Comment: Thanks . This worked. I needed to hide the jumbotron class from bootstrap in one of the pages. This is how I did it. 

<style>
.jumbotron {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}
</style>

Answer (score 70):

To hide an element, use:

```
display: none;
visibility: hidden;
```

To show an element, use:

```
display: block;
visibility: visible;
```

The difference is:

Visibility handles the visibility of the tag, the `display` handles space it occupies on the page.

If you set the `visibility` and do not change the `display`, even if the tags are not seen, *it still occupies space.*

Comment: why wouldn't one use just `display: none;` ?

Comment: The `visibility` rule is indeed redundant when you set `display:none`.  Note that a toggling `display` may cause surrounding elements to move as a result of space reallocation. If this "jumping" effect is undesired, one might want to use `visibility` *instead*.

Answer (score 16):

you can use any of the following five ways to hide element, depends upon your requirements.

### Opacity

```
.hide {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

### Visibility

```
.hide {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

### Display

```
.hide {
   display: none;
}
```

### Position

```
.hide {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
}
```

### clip-path

```
.hide {
  clip-path: polygon(0px 0px,0px 0px,0px 0px,0px 0px);
}
```

To show use any of the following: 
**opacity: 1;**
**visibility: visible;**
**display: block;**

Source : https://www.sitepoint.com/five-ways-to-hide-elements-in-css/

Answer (score 0):

Html Code :

```
    <a id="f">Show First content!</a>
    <br/>
    <a id="s">Show Second content!!</a>
    <div class="a">Default Content</div>
    <div class="ab hideDiv">First content</div>
    <div class="abc hideDiv">Second content</div>
```

Script code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#f").mouseover(function(){
        $('.a,.abc').addClass('hideDiv');
        $('.ab').removeClass('hideDiv');
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $('.a').removeClass('hideDiv');
        $('.ab,.abc').addClass('hideDiv');
    });

    $("#s").mouseover(function(){
        $('.a,.ab').addClass('hideDiv');
        $('.abc').removeClass('hideDiv');
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $('.a').removeClass('hideDiv');
        $('.ab,.abc').addClass('hideDiv');
    });
});
```

css code:

```
.hideDiv
{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.abc,.ab {
    display: none;
}
#f:hover ~ .ab {
    display: block;

}
#f:hover ~ .abc,.a {
    display: none;

}
#s:hover ~ .abc {
    display: block;

}
#s:hover ~ .ab,.a {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<a id="f">Show First content!</a>
<br/>
<a id="s">Show Second content!!</a>
<div class="a">Default Content</div>
<div class="ab">First content</div>
<div class="abc">Second content</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

html code :

```
<button class="Show">Show</button> 
<button class="Hide">Hide</button>
<button class="toggle">Show &amp; Hide</button>
<div id="target"></div>
```

css code :

```
#target {
  background:#0099cc;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  height:160px;
  padding:5px;
  display:none;
}

.Hide
{
  display:none;
}
```

javascript code :

```
    $('.Show').click(function() {
    $('#target').show(200);
    $('.Show').hide(0);
    $('.Hide').show(0);
});
    $('.Hide').click(function() {
    $('#target').hide(500);
    $('.Show').show(0);
    $('.Hide').hide(0);
});
    $('.toggle').click(function() {
    $('#target').toggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).