# Display and hide div elements with different parents using CSS

Tags: html, css

I've already checked out the question and subsequent answer on [how to hide a div with css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598568/display-and-hide-div-with-css), but I could not figure out how to make it work if the different elements aren't under the same parent. For example:

```
<head>
  <style>
    section .city {
      display: none;
    }

    nav .london:hover ~ section .london {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="city london">London</div>
  </nav>
  <section>
    <div class="city london">
      <p class="text">London text etc.</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Here, I'd like to only show the .text element when the appropriate div in the nav section is being hovered over. This works without the nav & section areas, as the divs become siblings, but how would I obtain the same behaviour while still using the nav and section tags?

Comment: there you want to traverse through parent of an element, which is not yet possible using html,css only. You need to use JS based solution for this.

Comment: thats not possible using CSS only

Comment: @Mike In this case, would not using the nav and section tags be recommended or should I just go ahead and use JavaScript?

Comment: Closest way to achieve is by calling the parent selectors - http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#4ee7868cb6ebb071fe61991b47c586cd

Comment: @MichaelSchwartz In the full code, I have multiple cities and want a specific text to show when the specific element in the navigation bar is being hovered over (not the entire nav bar). Is there still a way to do this?

Comment: The way you want to do it is not possible in CSS. You can do it in JS easily. In CSS however you [would have to change your markup](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#02f135244ce682a474922f2ba374de51).

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to do it using this [solution](https://blogs.perficient.com/2021/02/25/how-to-show-hide-html-elements-by-only-using-css/).

The label can be detached from <input type "checkbox" id="checkBtn">, only input element and the element to be hidden/shown on clicking the label must belong to the same parent.