# Can a Content within <i> </i> inside a <div></div> be hidden?

Tags: html, css, hide

I have HTML like this:

```
<div class="meta-box-1">
<p> Content 1 </p>
<i> Content 2 </i>
<h4> Content 3 </h4>
</div>
```

Can I hide Content 2? How?

I googled for it and it seems it can not be done. But being new to every kind of coding I could not become sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm wondering How you search and found nothing about ... https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=hide%20element%20css

Comment: Maybe he used Bing.

Comment: I really doubt you googled for it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24055535/2887133

Comment: Hi @DaniP I didn't say I found nothing. May be I could not figure out things correctly but it seemed to me that I may not do that. But since I doubted my own conclusion, I asked you guys for help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `div i { display: none; }` will solve the issue described above.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ocfv5exp/)

This will hide all `i` tags within `div` tags.

To hide all `i` tags within the specific `div` tag with the class `meta-box-1`, modify the CSS to:

```
.meta-box-1 i { display: none; }
```

Comment: Thanks @applesElmi. Your answer is really helpful. Sorry I could not upvote you because of my insufficient reputation. It, in fact, is 1-4=-3. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
div i {display:none;}
```

Adding this in your css file would hide all i tags that are stored within a div

Comment: Thanks @Smithy. Will this not hide all i tags within all the div elements? Shouldn't we use the class of the perticular div to hide only the i tag within it?

Comment: Yeah it would, if you add a class to the <i> tag then simply just replace the i in the css with a dot (.) followed by the name of the class